# iOS: Create project that share codes

Tags: ios, swift

Right now I have an iPhone app and all of the codes and resources are inside in one big project (one folder too).
Now I'm planning to create a separate iPad app (not universal) and I need to create a new project under the same workspace. There will be some codes and resources (xibs, models, services, images, fonts, external frameworks) that the 2 apps will share. So I plan to create another project that will contain these "common" things and the 2 projects will not access it there.

Question: How to do this? Is the 3rd project a custom framework?
Can someone point me to a tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have an Xcode workspace this is reasonably easy:

Create a new framework for your iPad app within the workspace

Create a new framework for your shared code and assets within the workspace. This needs to be a framework, not a library, as you will be sharing assets, and not just code. Move the shared code and resources to this project.

Add a dependency to this shared framework from your two projects.

Comment: I tried adding the shared framework under Embedded Binaries and Linked Frameworks and Libraries. I also added the Import statement. It cannot detect the class I added in the Shared project.

Comment: @iori24 Have you made the classes you want to share `public`?

Comment: @Abizem, You are right. After I made them public, I can see them now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to use target to separate them, if it bases on similar UI design between iPhone & iPad.

Step 1: find your target and click "Duplicate"

[image]

You could set up different parameter set by plist file

[image]

Comment: They don't have same UI